# TFS 2010 process template work item customisations

Tags: tfs-workitem

I've created a new default Process Template called "My Agile V2" and uploaded it successfully into our TFS repository.

I also have some exported work item definition files, i.e. Bug.xml and UserStory.xml which have some customisations made to them i.e. adding a few additional fields and the like. We already successfully use these customised work items on some of our existing projects..

But I'd now like to include these customised work items in as part of the new "My Agile V2" Process Template so that every time we create a new project, we don't have to import these same bug.xml and userstory.xml files every single time.

I managed to export "Download" an existing Process Template, overwrite its bug.xml and userstory.xml files in the "WorkItem Tracking > TypeDefinitions" folder and then re-upload it. The Upload worked, however the work item customisations didn't come through whatsoever. I.e. they still have default behaviour and none of my custom fields...

Where am I going wrong???

Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think just importing WITs is not enough. Have a look at the page for [Adding a Work Item Instance to a Process Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243867%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)